# How to connect a internal DVD writer to PC via USB Adapater

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, dvd

I would like to know if I can connect my internal DVD writter to PC using a USB adapter. Myproblem is that I have a old computer and have a IDE DVD writer. I want that to be connected to my laptop using IDE to USB connector.

Here is what I tried:

Connected my internal DVD writter to Laptop using IDE to USB connector, well, it looked like all is going to work as expected. But no.. I dont see the DVD writter recognized by the computer. I suspect if that need a USB driver for the writer to work. If it needs a driver then, I don't think my plan is going to work since i dont think internal drive have respective USB drives that fact is that it don't need one.

Comment: Unless you're using a very old OS, such as Win98, USB support will be in-built, at least for reading. Writing may need a separate application. Check the hardware by plugging into another system.

Comment: What IDE to USB adapter are you using? I assume you are providing power to the DVD writer through the Molex connector, you can eject the tray to see if it is receiving power. Also make sure to set the jumper on the drive to Master (or try Slave if it doesn't work).

Comment: Hi AFH and Aleix, Thank you for your prompt response. I am using Windows 7 OS. For writing i have Nero installed in the computer. And by IDE to USB adapater i mean by is this (http://www.pimfg.com/ifaq/images/usb-ide40-power-1.jpg). The power to the DVD writter is good, as i can open the tray and close it while it is powered on via IDE to USB adapater. But i could see is that it doesn't not show the drive in device manager and also in my computer .

Comment: Can you try with a hard drive? When you plug it, a USB device should appear in device manager (with the DVD drive, the hard drive, or even with nothing attached). If nothing appears in device manager, I'm afraid it's not going to work.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. Yes i had tried connecting an internal hardisk to my computer using the IDE to USB adapater. It works. I am able to see the drive listed in "Disk Drive" section of Device manager. But not my DVD writter. i guess so.. this may not work..

Comment: Some USB-to-IDE adapters only work with harddrives, some work with both harddrives and CD/DVD drivers. (Same for ATA-to-IDE adapters). At least we need the exact brand and model of your adapter to check that, if the information can be found with googling.

Comment: NS-SV, you did not provide information about the jumper setting. Did you understand the hint of Aleix?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a driver issue. It most likely would have recognized the drive during boot and isn't compatible with your usb host controller. I would:

- Connect the drive internally to a PC and then navigate to the Driver Details in Device Manager.
- Download and install the windows drivers to your laptop (remember to always create a recovery before manually moving any system files).
- Reconnect and restart your laptop with the drive (and external power) connected.